# JButton's ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcheckbox

In the code below, when both _uiChkTestAction and _uiChkTestItem JCheckBox are unselected, clicking bu1 button make them both selected, but clicking bu2 button does not change _uiChkTestItem JCheckBox from being unselected to selected.

So, is there something wrong with my code ?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class TestActionItemListener
{
public static void main(String[] _args)
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

    public void run(){

    JFrame _fra = new JFrame("Testing");
    _fra.setSize(500, 500);
    _fra.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    final JCheckBox _uiChkTestAction = new JCheckBox("ActionListener");
    _uiChkTestAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent _ev)
        {
            System.out.println("State by ActionListener: " + _uiChkTestAction.isSelected());
        }
    });

    final JCheckBox _uiChkTestItem = new JCheckBox("ItemListener");
    _uiChkTestItem.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
    {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("State by ItemListener: " + _uiChkTestAction.isSelected());
        }
    });
    JButton bu1 = new JButton("actionlistener bu");
    bu1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          _uiChkTestAction.setSelected(true);
        }
     });
    JButton bu2 = new JButton("itemlistener bu");
    bu1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        _uiChkTestItem.setSelected(true);
        }
     });
    _fra.add(_uiChkTestAction);
    _fra.add(_uiChkTestItem);
    _fra.add(bu1);
    _fra.add(bu2);
    _uiChkTestAction.setSelected(true);
    _uiChkTestItem.setSelected(true);

    _fra.setVisible(true);
}}
);
}
};
```

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add both of your listeners to the same button `bu1` iso adding one to `bu1` and one to `bu2`

Comment: @FffDgg There is no reason to close the question. Just mark it as answered as you did is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a listener to `bu1` twice. Add the second one to `bu2`.